# POSTGRESQL: DUMP TABLE WITHOUT TOAST DATA

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to isolate toast data from a table so that I can dump the table without the toast data. I know there must be a way to do that, but I cant get my way there...Suggestions would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try a [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) (or psql's \copy) with the query option - you can select the columns to export. You can also choose a CSV format rather than tab-separated, the representation of nulls etc.

Answer (score 0):

[TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/storage-toast.html) is the way how PostgreSQL is storing your data *internally*. For you, as a user, there is only values that you delegated to the database to keep for you.

TOAST comes into play mostly for the textual data, when any of the tuple's attributes make tuple's size to be more then 8k (if PostgreSQL compiled with default page size). This happens inside the DB engine, transparently to the user. Say, if you'll insert a row with a text that has round 10k symbols, the corresponding attribute will be TOASTed.

Given how TOAST works, your question appears to look like: *How do I dump table without attributes containing big chunks of data?* It seems unclear for me what would be the purpose of this, as your dump will be incomplete.

---

**EDIT:** I don't know how to find if any attribute of any tuple do have a TOASTed value. Instead, I will eliminate all attributes that *can have* TOASTed values.

The following query will give you all the columns for a table, that are always in `PLAIN` storage mode:

```sql
SELECT a.attname
  FROM pg_class t
  JOIN pg_attribute a ON t.oid = a.attrelid
  JOIN pg_type typ ON typ.oid = a.atttypid
 WHERE t.relkind='r' AND t.relname = 'element'
   AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
   AND typ.typstorage='p'
 ORDER BY a.attnum;
```

And this query will generate the desired `SQL`, you can wrap it in the script or into the PL/pgSQL's `EXECUTE` statement:

```
SELECT 'COPY '||quote_ident(t.relname)||
       '('||string_agg(a.attname, ',' ORDER BY a.attnum)||') TO stdout;'
  FROM pg_class t
  JOIN pg_attribute a ON t.oid = a.attrelid
  JOIN pg_type typ ON typ.oid = a.atttypid
 WHERE t.relkind='r' AND t.relname = '<YOUR_TABLE>'
   AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
   AND typ.typstorage='p'
 GROUP BY t.relname;
```

Comment: Hello @vyegorov I dont need the TOASTed columns. I want to dump all other data into something like xls, for some reasons. I wouldn't mind if you went ahead and advised me on what I have mentioned above...